# How to open submenu while hover into parent menu item

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I am developing wp theme and coded for navigation. Everything looks good but when I hover to menu item, it does not open sub-menu. I think there is some problem with my css coding. Could you please help me.

```css
.f-nav .menu {
    background-color: hotpink;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    color: white;

    > .menu-item {
        margin: 0;
        > a {
            padding: 1rem;
            border-bottom: none;
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            border-left: 1px solid #222;
            }
        &:hover a, &.open > a {
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }

        > .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background: #fff;
            display: none;
            min-width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #efefef;
            border-top-color: #fff;
            z-index: 10;
        }
    }   
    nav {
        position: relative;
    }
    .current-menu-item {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .menu-item-home {
        background-color: blue;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the html code too?

Comment: Please include complete code (better a working fiddle/snippet), that will help to understand your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that on hover, you will display it:
Add to your code:

```
&:hover a, &.open > a {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
    .sub-menu { display: block} /* <-- Add this line*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add to hover css in menu-item

```
> .menu-item {
  &:hover {
    > .sub-menu {
       display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Check working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x4cszvjq/)

Comment: Please check out here.
http://imxishananwar7851-com.stackstaging.com/New/

You can login http://imxishananwar7851-com.stackstaging.com/New/wp-login.php
username: Admin
password: Admin

Comment: I have added my css and it's working fine `.f-nav .menu > .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {  display: block;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the markup

```html
<nav class="f-nav" role="navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' 
        )); ?>
   </nav>
```

here is navigation.php

```html
<?php 
function _testcopy_register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'main-menu' => esc_html__('My Primary Menu', '_testcopy'),
        'footer-menu' => esc_html__('My Footer Menu', '_testcopy'),
    ));
}
add_action('init','_testcopy_register_menus');
```